# How to create Chrome notification for my changes in website?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web, notifications

How to create google chrome extension with a notification for every change in my website page ?

Comment: Do you Even Google bro? Try these... http://lifehacker.com/5857721/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension/all....
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/os-extendchrome/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If your site has RSS feed, you can do something like this (only new pages):

Get and parse RSS feed using jQuery:

```
$.get('http://yoursite.com/rss', function(data) {
   $(data).find('item').each(function() {
      var url_news = $(this).find('link').text();
      var news_id = $(this).find('id').text();
      var descr = $(this).find('title').text();
   });
});
```

Show Notify using Chrome Notification
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications

```
var title = "Title";
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(img, title, descr);
   notification.onclick = function() {
      chrome.tabs.create({url: url_news}, notification.cancel());
      chrome.windows.getLastFocused(null, function(win){
         if(win.state=="minimized"){
            chrome.windows.update(win.id, {state:"normal", focused:true});
         }
      });
   };
   notification.show();
```

When updated your rss feed, chrome extension will display notifications